# Dynamodb GSI query response is very slow

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a dynamodb table which contains information of the status of different cron jobs.

Table attributes:

- id [HashKey]
- jobId [RangeKey]
- status ('failed','pending', 'success')

I want to query the items based on the job `status` field.

Eg: list all jobs which are in `pending` state?

So I created the GSI as below.

GSI:

```
{
        IndexName: 'StatusIndex',
    
        KeySchema: [
          {
            AttributeName: 'status',
            KeyType: 'HASH',
          },
        ],
        Projection: {
          ProjectionType: 'ALL',
        },
      },
```

But the query on GSI is very slow when all the items contains same `status` value.

| id | jobId | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | job1 | pending |
| 2 | job2 | pending |
| 3 | job3 | pending |
| 4 | job4 | pending |

Is this because of not having range key?

Comment: How slow?  What performance are you seeing and what are you expecting?  Can you should us how you are querying the index?

Comment: And how many items in the GSI?

Answer (score 0):

You might be better of with a [Parallel Scan](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html#Scan.ParallelScan) here. A Query does not have parallel  functionality. If you're trying to get a very large amount of data in one Query, it will be slow. If you use a Parallel Scan, set the number of threads to match the number of MBs of data in your table to optimise the speed. This will cost you more RCUs than a Query.

Alternatively you can consider remodeling your data. You will need a way of running multiple Queries to access the desired data, and a way of running them in parallel from your client. One option you can consider is breaking the data down into [time series](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-time-series.html).